# C# - Most effficient way to match type and value

Tags: c#, generics, types, .net-core

I'm developing EVE Online application. EVE API provides [very many](https://esi.evetech.net/ui/?version=latest#/) different data, and I want to write generic methods for all of them.

My idea is to write generic method that "extracts" path to API from passed type and sends appropriate request. For example:

```
interface ICommonResponse
{
    //some method or property
}

class FwLeaderboards : ICommonResponse
{
    //some fields corresponding to api response
}

public T Get<T>() where T : ICommonResponse
{
    string path = SomeMagic(T); //we "extract" path from type
    return Send<T>(path); //this method retrieves JSON string from api and deserializes it to object of FwLeaderboards type
}
```

How to extract path?
Unfortunately, it is illegal to call static members of `T` directly. So, I see three ways.

#### Reflection

```
abstract class CommonResponse
{
    public static string Path() => null;
}

class FwLeaderboards : CommonResponse
{
    new public static string Path() => "/fw/leaderboards/";
    //some fields corresponding to api response
}

public T Get<T>() where T : CommonResponse
{
    string path = (string)typeof(T).GetMethod("Path").Invoke(null,null);
    return Send<T>(path);
}
```

#### Instantiation

We create an instance of class and call method.

```
interface ICommonResponse
{
    string Path() => null;
}

class FwLeaderboards : ICommonResponse
{
    public override string Path() => "/fw/leaderboards/";
    //some fields corresponding to api response
}

public T Get<T>() where T : ICommonResponse, new()
{
    T val = new T();
    return Send<T>(val.Path());
}
```

#### Dictionary

We have a `Dictionary` (or any other collection) with `Type` as key.

```
IDictionary<Type, string> dict = ...;//Initialize dictionary

interface ICommonResponse
{
}

class FwLeaderboards : ICommonResponse
{
    //some fields corresponding to api response
}

public T Get<T>() where T : ICommonResponse
{
    var path = dict[typeof(T)]; //returns "/fw/leaderboards/" for FwLeaderboards
    return Send<T>(val.Path());
}
```

So, what is the **most efficient way**?

Comment: where exactly the `get` method located?

Comment: @Progressive In my EveClient service. It doesn't matter, response classes aren't nested nor private

Comment: you can pass ICommonResponse object to Get method and reach `.Path` directly. Composing `ICommonResponse` fits your situation very well tho. Or you know, you can create an `ICommonRequest`

Comment: I wouldn't store the request url inside a response object, since it feels out of place there (the url is used for the request, not response).  Also some requests require additional parameters as well so you need to know what to submit. Also taking a look at ESI.NET, EVEStandard or another Eve Online library out there might save you some time re-implementing the API yourself.